# Does not return last element after reversing

Tags: c++

So I have to make a program where I first put in an array of strings and then insertion sort it, output that, then reverse the array and output it again. I'm just having one little problem. The last element (after reversing, originally the first element) doesn't print? I'm betting this is an easy fix, but does anyone know how to fix it? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string insertionSort(string[], int);
string reverseSort(string[], int);

string insertionSort(string words[], int numWords) {
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
string temp = "";

for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
  j = i;
  while (j > 0 && words[j] < words[j - 1]) {
     temp = words[j];
     words[j] = words[j - 1];
     words[j - 1] = temp;
     j--;
    }
}
return temp;
}

string insertionSortRev(string words[], int numWords) { //reverse array
int start = 0;
int end = numWords;
string temp = "";

while (start < end) {
  string temp = words[start];
  words[start] = words[end];
  words[end] = temp;
  start++;
  end--;
  }
  return temp;
  }


int main() {
string words[] = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
int numWords = 0;

cin >> numWords;

for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
cin >> words[i];
}

cout << "UNSORTED: ";
for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
cout << words[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

insertionSort(words, numWords);

 cout << "SORTED: ";
 for(int z = 0; z < numWords; z++) {
    cout << words[z] << " ";
 }
 cout << endl;

 insertionSortRev(words, numWords);

 cout << "REVERSED: ";
 for (int k = 0; k < numWords; k++) {
 cout << words[k] << " ";
 }
 cout << endl;

 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: You're right, this is a very easy fix.  One that is probably easy to see when you step thru the code in your debugger.  Learning to use the debugger is of far more benefit to you than asking repeated questions here about your code as it evolves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of size `s` is indexed from `0` to `s-1`. In your reverse function, write `end = numWords - 1;` instead of `end = numWords`.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple

Comment: As an aside, name your reverse function `reverseArray` or something similar. It does not sort the given array, so naming it `insertionSortRev` is misleading.